# Could you suggest a simple pub/sub mechanism which works without configuration/installation?

Tags: .net, publish-subscribe

We are looking for a simple pub/sub mechanism, in which one C# application publishes messages which can then be subscribed to by other applications running across the network.

We do not need to persist messages. Clients subscribe to specific messages when they come online and get alerted when a matching message is available.

I am already aware of the following:

- nservicebus (Licensing issues, free license is too restrictive)
- rabbitmq (Excellent choice, unfortunately we make clinical software and hardware and have very long release cycles. We also have more than 20K deployments worldwide and are wary of introducing another dependency which will need to be installed and maintained)
- zeromq (Looks promising. Have not heard a lot  about it in the .Net world. Although I could use the bindings available on nuget and get it to work, I am wary of finding bugs as I do not see a lot of downloads or adoption for the .Net bindings)
- Write our own over msmq or WCF (this is the last resort)

What other alternatives can you suggest? We would prefer something which is free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

[Muscle](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/index.html) Free and open source.

Comment: Good one...had never heard of it! Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is http://signalr.net, however I am not sure if it supports pub/sub out of the box. There's a project doing [real time Push Notifications with SignalR & PNotify.](http://www.msguy.com/2011/11/real-time-push-notifications-with.html)

The SignalR library is written in C# and JS and was created by Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. It's licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at MQTT (http://mqtt.org). Its and extremely light weight pub/sub protocol designed to run on embedded systems. It doesn't give a lot of the bells and whistles that comes with AMQP based message brokers such as rabbitMQ, but it works beautiful for simple efficient pub/sub requirements.
An open-source server for MQTT is the mosquito project, Clients for MQTT are available in various languages under the Paho project.